# Online Platforms where simulate board/card game

Tags: playing-cards, prototyping

With my mates I would like to design a new card-game. However due to lockdown and pandemic limitations, we cannot meet each other for playing sessions.

Does exists an online website/platform where I can replicate our game and make some test-sessions with colleagues?

I want to replicate:

- Only-text cards: right now I do not care about good graphycs and images.
- Table with game play
- Dice

Comment: I believe https://playingcards.io/ has the functionality that you want (they claim that you can add your own custom cards).

Answer (score 3):

Try Tabletop Simulator on Steam: https://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/Tabletop_Simulator/

It has the both the ability to upload custom components and to play multiplayer board games virtually.  I've used it for remote prototype testing myself.